# Inner Div With Image CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive

Having the following:

```
<div class="big-container">
    <div class="header">many things here that must be fixed on top of the page</div>

    <div class="content">
        <img src="image"/> <!--Must expand the content div to the size of the image -->
        <div class="footer"> Must be inside the image but at the bottom</div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- .content and .header must be at the same top, .content is much higher than header-->
```

I was trying with relative and absolute but the page being responsive, i can not set the height of the .content

What is the css?

Comment: many things "here" - where ? please provide more info than this. Probably a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can not just ask for code without even given a try. check below code. it might be helpful.

```css
.header{
background:red;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}

.content{
margin-top: 30px;
position: relative;
min-width: 300px;
max-width: 500px;
}
.content img{
position: relative;
height: 300px;
width: 100%;
}
.content .footer{
background: gray;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-container">
    <div class="header">many things here that must be fixed on top of the page</div>

    <div class="content">
        <img src="http://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/cx_633/cy_0/cw_1725/ch_1725/w_720/APL/uploads/2014/11/too-cute-doggone-it-video-playlist.jpg"/> <!--Must expand the content div to the size of the image -->
        <div class="footer"> Must be inside the image but at the bottom</div>
    </div>
</div>
```